# How to get tablet's IMEI number?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10-desktop

This is not WinRT application. It's standard WPF. The device behaves as normal Windows PC, has Windows 10 installed. It has 3G broadband modem and a SIM card slot.

Answer (score 2):

Some more information would be helpful. For example the brand and connection type (usb/internal).

If I understood you correctly you are looking for a solution to programmatically (in wpf) collect information (imei) about connected modems (in general or only one specific?)
Depending on the device you have several options.

**Option 1 WMI:**

Depending if the manufacturer included the information you might be successful by an simple WMI query.

To verify this take a look at the Device Manager (start -> run -> devmgmt.msc)

Right Click on your Modem -> Properties
Now go the register "Details".

Scroll through the Properties and look for your IMEI (the property doesn't necessarily is named IMEI). If you find it there, you can use a WMI Query to get the information into your WPF program.
Example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/448125/How-to-write-WMI-Query-to-find-USB-MODEMS-IN-Cshar

**Option 2 AT Commands:**

If you are able to communicate with the modem over serial connection you can use so called "AT-Commands" to get the IMEI.
Information about the AT Commands can be found here: http://www.developershome.com/sms/atCommandsIntro.asp

Comment: Unfortunately, both options failed with my device. The modem is described by Windows as modem broadband network interface, it's not visible in Device Manager. There is COM1 port visible, but it's not a part of the modem or its driver. It behaves as purely virtual or disconnected device. The only thing that works with the device is "netsh mbn show interface" - i use it now, but I'm still curious how to get this data without issuing an external command.

Comment: didn't know about the mbn in netsh so far, nice input! If windows has the information available, which it has, else it wouldn't be in netsh mbn, I'm pretty sure its available through wmi query. Check through your WMI using for example WMI Explorer (https://wmie.codeplex.com/) - I see its a RT device so you may have not direct application access, probably you find a similar app in the store. - Another option is querying the WMI over your local network, since you can query remotely.

Comment: couldn't edit anymore, In addition I can't believe its not in the device manager, check all categories and use (View -> Show hidden devices)

Comment: I found it. It's listed as network adapter "CDC MBIM". But I couldn't find "Device Id" property anywhere in its properties.